# Cloze package: Hyphenation does not work (anymore?)

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, underline, cloze

I use the `cloze` package to create cloze texts. The documentation states specifically (p. 4):

> The command `\cloze` doesn’t change the behavior of the hyphenation.

But when I try the given example, I see that words are not properly hyphenated anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cloze}
\begin{document}
Telekommunikationsüberwachung geht Unternehmenssteuerfortentwicklungsgesetz
\cloze{Telekommunikationsüberwachung} geht \cloze{Unternehmenssteuerfortentwicklungsgesetz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation result]

Can someone confirm this? Is this "fixable"? What worries me is that I kind of remember that hyphenation worked when I tested it a while ago.

Comment: I tried the example enabling German hyphenation; the result is the same (no hyphenation) with TeX Live 2015, 2016 and 2017/pretest.

Comment: The source code of the documentation shows that you have to insert hyphenation points: `\cloze{Unter\-nehmens\-steuer\-fort\-entwicklungs\-gesetz}`

Answer (score 3):

If I look in the source for the documentation (file `cloze.dtx`), I see

```
\begin{clozeexample}
es
\cloze{Te\-le\-kom\-mu\-ni\-ka\-tions\-ü\-ber\-wach\-ung}
geht
\cloze{Un\-ter\-neh\-mens\-steu\-er\-fort\-ent\-wick\-lungs\-ge\-setz}
\cloze{Ab\-teil\-ungs\-lei\-ter\-in}
\cloze{Ober\-kom\-mi\-sar\-in}
auch
\cloze{Fil\-lial\-lei\-ter\-in}
kurz
\cloze{Ober\-kom\-mi\-sar\-in}
\cloze{Un\-ter\-neh\-mens\-steu\-er\-fort\-ent\-wick\-lungs\-ge\-setz}
\cloze{Fil\-lial\-lei\-ter\-in}
\cloze{Metz\-ger\-mei\-ster\-in}
in
\cloze{Ab\-teil\-ungs\-lei\-ter\-in}
der
\cloze{Ober\-kom\-mi\-sar\-in}
\cloze{Hoch\-lei\-stungs\-flüs\-sig\-keits\-chro\-ma\-to\-gra\-phie}
\cloze{Fil\-lial\-lei\-ter\-in}
Kürze
\cloze{Un\-ter\-neh\-mens\-steu\-er\-fort\-ent\-wick\-lungs\-ge\-setz}
\cloze{Metz\-ger\-mei\-ster\-in}
liegt
\cloze{Ab\-teil\-ungs\-lei\-ter\-in}
die
\cloze{Metz\-ger\-mei\-ster\-in}
\cloze{Ab\-teil\-ungs\-lei\-ter\-in}
Würze
\cloze{Ober\-kom\-mi\-sar\-in}
\end{clozeexample}
```

and indeed, when this is compiled, hyphenation is OK.

On the other hand, this seems to reproduce your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cloze}

\begin{document}

\parbox{2cm}{
  \cloze{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
}

\bigskip

\parbox{2cm}{
  supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
  \cloze{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
}

\bigskip

\parbox{2cm}{
 x
 \cloze{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that if `\cloze` comes after a space, it doesn't allow hyphenation. If I change the second example into

```
\parbox{2cm}{
  supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
  \cloze{\hspace{0pt}supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
}
```

then the result is as expected:

[image]

A possible fix, but it works only with TeX Live 2017 (pretest, LuaTeX 1.0.4)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cloze}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\cloze}{#2}{\hspace{0pt}#2}{}{}

\begin{document}

\parbox{2cm}{
  \cloze{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
}

\bigskip

\parbox{2cm}{
  supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
  \cloze{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
}

\bigskip

\parbox{2cm}{
 x
 \cloze{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post! Unfortunately, neither the patch nor inserting `\hspace{0pt}` manually into the argument (i.e. `\cloze{\hspace{0pt}Unternehmenssteuerfortentwicklungsgesetz}`) works with my minimal example.

Comment: @FlorianL It works for me, but unfortunately only with TL 2017/pretest. I added the information.